# python program + sudo shutdown after python ends (best way without prompting for pw after first half?)

Tags: bash, shell-script, sudo

I'm curious about the best way (most secure way) to execute a python program and after it ends shutdown the system (using sudo in a ssh session).

What I would do initially is:

`nohup python py_name.py && sudo shutdown -h now &` or
`nohup python py_name.py ; sudo shutdown -h now &`

(`sudo` because I'm in a ssh session and I can't shutdown without it and `nohup` and `&` because I want to leave the system after executing)

The problems is that the python program is like 5-8 hour long and I don't want the shell prompt for pw after that (is somehow possible to prompt when executing first command?). My system is ubuntu 18.04 so I guess that "sudoing" both can't work because of the timeout of sudo (15 min?).

One option is to enter superuser mode for both commands or scripting it and executing `sudo ./script`, but is it secure taking into account that it is executing a python program? (It's an easy home PC setup so maybe it's not a problem)

Is there any other way I'm not aware of?

----- EDIT -----

I tried to run `sudo sh -c 'python py_name.py && sudo shutdown -h now'`. `sudo sh -c 'command'` executes another shell to run the command and it could work this way because all the shell is in sudo. The problem is that I use a python environment and this new shell does not come activated with it.

-----SOLUTION-----

The real solution is as said (by solution), changing the sudoers file `sudo visudo` to add shutdown to the list that does not need password when it runs `sudo shutdown`. Each sudoers file is different, but in my case, I needed to add `my_username  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown`, where the first "space" is tab, and `/sbin/shutdown` is the path to the command you want to execute (you can check path with `command -v shutdown`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set for this user passwordless sudo in /etc/sudoers file.
e.g. on ssh server (also can be more restrictive of course, i.e. allowing only shutdown to be paswordless etc):

youruser       ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: oh cool, and you know if running a python script in sudo is secure if done in my home PC (only user) using ssh in local network?

Comment: @AurelieNavir if it is your own home single user machine, the only problem I see is that you can screw something up with your system by running python ( obviously depends what your python does ) as superuser. But why? use sudo only with shutdown.

Comment: yep, no problem then I guess. Thx